# The .git directory and security

Tags: git, security

Theoretically, if someone came into possession of one on my .git directories (but no source code at all), would they be able to recover any code?

Comment: Not just *any* of it, but *all* of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in `.git/objects` folder is git database with all objects (blobs, commits, tags and trees). Whole history is available in .git folder.

For details you can take a look into [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).